# Order of executing Chef recipes in a single cookbook

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a single cookbook with two recipes: `recipe/install.rb` and `recipe/configure.rb`.

In `install.rb`, I install all packages, `gem_package`s and `configure`, using them in `configure.rb`. I am installing one `gem_package` in `install.rb`, and using it as `require <that-gem>` in `configure.rb`.

Regardless of the order of runlist, chef-client execution fails mentioning `<that-gem>` is missing. If I run with `install` recipe first and then run `configure` recipe, things work fine. Isn't there a way where a single chef-run runs both the recipes in order? I tried mentioning `include_recipe` and all possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two phases to a Chef client run.

- First is the resource compilation stage, where all the ruby is
  loaded, node attributes are resolved and a run list generated.
- Next is the execution phase, where the recipes in the run list
  are executed.

Gems that your recipes rely on need to be available by the execution stage which presents a bit of a chicken or the egg problem, so you need to use a few tricks to get the gems installed first.

When installing gems for Chef to use, install them with [`chef_gem`](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_chef_gem.html).

```
chef_gem "your_gem"

require 'your_gem'
```

This can get a bit tricky if you start using gems in [libraries](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_libraries.html), as libraries are required at compile time and you can't get actions to occur before compile time. In this case you need to fail nicely on the load so the gem can be installed.

```
begin
  require 'your_gem'
rescue LoadError
  warn "Load of [your_gem] failed. Should be installed by install.rb"
end
```

Then be sure not to use any of the objects the gem provides in the Chef run before the install can occur.

Comment: This isn't actually true. The `chef_gem` resource automatically runs at compile-time (no need to use `run_action`). It also clears the Gem paths. You **do** still need to require it.

Comment: Thanks. Was morphing it across from `gem_package`.